# Storing backups on a remote filesystem

Tags: backup, nfs, iscsi, sshfs

I have a FreeNAS solution, in which I'll would like to save my backups. Currently I was doing some scripting to rsync/tarball, but I want a something more easy to manage, so I figure out, to run a simple backup solution on a different server, while storing the backups at the FreeNAS server.

Both server are located on a 1Gbit LAN.
I was planning to use NFS, to export a filesystem from FreeNAS and mount it on the "Backup director".

Is NFS a good idea? Should I try something else like sshfs, iSCSI, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to give a look at [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/): it basically is a perl wrapper around rsync with the added benefits of integrated snapshot rotation and much more.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look. Do you have any comments on the filesystem question?

Comment: I think the best thing would be to install [rsnapshot directly on the FreeNAS machine](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/need-help-on-how-to-install-rsnapshot-on-freenas.19003/), without going the NFS route. If this is not possible, then NFS is the best alternative.